# Money supply vs inflation - repository of raw data?

Tags: inflation, money-supply, data-request

I would like to do may own analysis of the relationship between the money supply and inflation. Can anyone suggest a good source for raw data? I would like to have access to data for multiple countries going back multiple decades. Perhaps someone has already made a neatly packaged repository of such data?

**EDIT:** In response to the comment about lack of details. This was kind of deliberate because I was taking the attitude of "beggars can't be choosers" so I would take whatever I was given. But if someone out there knows of multiple different repositories and was wondering which one to tell me about then here would be my preferences...

With regard money supply measures: I know that different counties have different notation. So for example M1 in the UK does not mean the same thing as M1 in the US. What I would like is as close as possible to the sum of demand deposits plus notes and coins in circulation.

With regard inflation measures, again each country will do its own thing, so something analogous to CPI would be good.

With regard frequency, higher is better, preferably monthly.

When I say "neatly packaged" I simply meant "in one location". I was hoping that perhaps someone that wrote a paper on inflation vs money supply might have put all the data they used at some single URL or zip file (wishful thinking perhaps).

Comment: This question lacks details and clarity. Source of what raw data? What sort of model you want to estimate? Or you want just money supply and inflation without any controls? There are also different measures of inflation and money supply, do you want M1, M2 or M3, what sort of inflation you want, one constructed from core CPI, CPI or CPIH? What frequency? Also how do you define 'neatly packaged repository of such data'. Virtually any source of raw data will require you to put some work into processing that data. Processed datasets are not raw anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a great source of data - the [IMF eLibrary Data](https://data.imf.org/) site. It's free, it goes back many decades and covers a great many countries.